# Is there a way to have ephemeral access_keys for users in AWS via roles without another access_key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, access-keys

It is a common case where you would use roles for user accounts in AWS, assuming a role from one aws account into another.
For this example there is an "empty" account in AWS I'll call the Access Account only for individual users to log into. There is zero infrastructure in the account.  Then there is, a second account that has infrastructure running, which I will call Prod.
For the console access, a user would log into the Access account then assume a role in the Prod account. This is pretty straight forward.

For access_keys, and CLI: My understanding is user would have to have an access_key and secret in the Access account.  After doing a small bit of configuration, user can then send commands via the CLI. It will allow the user to run command agaist prod if their Access key matches to a role in prod and that role has the correct permissions  I have tested this and it works fine.

The question is, is there a better way to do this? With this method above for access_keys, the user still needs to have a long lived access_key in the Access account. Therefore, the user should still have to be rotating thier Access account access_key periodically.

Is there another way to get a short lived temporary access_key to Prod without needing a long lived access_key in the Access account?

Comment: If the only thing that your users need is AWS CLI, why not let them login in to some EC2 instance, and use EC2 role for the CLI operations?

Comment: educate your user to assume role using CLI. guidance here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/

Answer (score 1):

To have only short-term credentials in your AWS environment, you want to look in to [federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/).

The pattern you've described is a valid one, but you're correct that the users will still have long-term credentials. At least in this "identity account" model you have one location to manage and monitor (and revoke!) those credentials.